# How to access attributes from linked tables (QGIS 2.14.2 Essen)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins, table-of-contents

I have one source shapefile like this:  It consist the geographical coordinates of weather stations:

[image]

And several attribute files, which contain the Temperature data of each date for several years

[image]

I managed to linked them through the ID (project properties/ Relations).

Now I want to access for example the Temperature from the weather station 3 at a specific date. With the attribute table I can see all the values, but I don't know how to query some values with the Field Calculator.
I can’t access the linked data.

Comment: Haven't really used _Project Relations_ so I would probably suggest **Joining** the shapefile to your attribute files instead. You can do this by accessing your source layer properties (right-click your layer) and (assuming your German) select `Eigenshaften > Verknüpfungen`, add the attribute files and select the `ID` fields to join with the relevant field from the source layer. Once done, open the _Attribute Table_ for your source layer, click the bottom-left button and select `Fortgeschrittener Filter` and use an expression like `"ID" = 3 AND "Date" = '2014-01-01'`.

Comment: "I dont know how to query some values with the Field Calculator" - can you elaborate on this? What exactly are you trying to achieve? (eg get the count of related features? or the sum of some attribute of related features?)

Comment: Thank for you your response.  Now I want to access for example the Temperature from the weather station 3 at a specific date, but i want to use the field calculator of the source attribute table